# How do I validate that either one field or another is filled out in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have contact information. The user needs to fill out at least one of three fields, those fields being their email address, mailing address, or phone number.

How would I do this in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: by writing some code - so kindly add some attempt you made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what Justin shows may be fine, Rails does provide a formal scheme for doing just this type of thing.  It allows you to create a custom validator just like any of the predefined validators.

See "[validates_with](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with)" for more details, but here is the example from the Rails guide:

```
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.first_name == "Evil"
      record.errors[:base] << "This person is evil"
    end
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with GoodnessValidator
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone can give you a *better* answer, but this will do. You can just write your own method to check if those fields are blank. If they are blank, render an error.

```
validate :at_least_one

def at_least_one
  return unless email.blank? && address.blank? && phone.blank?

  errors.add(:base, 'Error message') # you can add the error to the base or even a particular attribute.
end
```

Comment: Okay, cool. That's kind of what I expected. I'm used to codeigniter where you write validation methods for _everything_, so this whole validation handles itself thing is strange and different to me.

Comment: Rails just has built in methods that you can use. You can always write your own to extend theirs.

Comment: Yeah, I was just kinda wondering there was a crazy nifty way of doing things. I looked around but didn't find anything so I figured I would ask.